# Virtualenv command not found on mac

Tags: python-3.x, macos, virtualenv

I have tried many solutions on SO and other sites but I am still unable to use the command `virtualenv`.

What is the appropriate way to install the same on mac?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bmacos%5D+%5Bvirtualenv%5D+install

Comment: can you show which solutions you tried so we don't waste our time suggesting things you've already done?

Answer (score 3):

First simple DO

```
$ pip install virtualenv
```

If you have a project in a directory called my-project you can set up virtualenv for that project by running:

```
$ cd my-project/
$ virtualenv venv
```

Now Active the environment

```
$ source venv/bin/activate
```